# CHange sql table value by the time

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a table with time column.

```
CREATE TABLE `mbusGuestCodeExpires` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hashOfUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `expiresTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hashOfUser` (`hashOfUser`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PACK_KEYS=0;
```

and input which has value of this field and user can change it, where `$expireTime` is time from table and `$timeDiffHour` and `$timeDiffMinute` are time left to time from table.

```
    echo        "<div class='expires'>Expires:<input type='text' class='expiresTime' value='{$expireTime}'/></div><div class='left'>";
            if (($timeDiffHour>=0) && ($timeDiffMinute>0))
             {
                echo"Left:".$timeDiffHour."h. ".$timeDiffMinute." min.";
             }
            echo"</div>";
```

I need now change the field active to 0 when it is `$expireTime` time. What is the best way to do it except running cron script every minute that check all the column and checks its value if it's less current time?

Comment: `select ... where expiresTime < curtime()`?

Comment: If you write it as an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
select ... where expiresTime < curtime()
```

Doc ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curtime